# How can i extract " \" "from json register in java

Tags: java, json

I'm working with a java's library (Gson) to store new Users in a file named "users.json). When i register a new one, my code reads previous data in the file to convert and add with the new data in a List of Users to write the new content to the json file.
The problem comes when the previous data are readed, because it's stored like the next example:

```
[
  {
    "name": "First",
    "second_name": "User",
    "age": "27",
    "email": "data1email@email.com",
    "user_id": "UtPdadq",
    "password": "email1Password123"
  }
]
```

and with new data:

```
[
  {
    "name": "\"First\"",
    "second_name": "\"User\"",
    "age": "\"27\"",
    "email": "\"data1email@email.com\"",
    "user_id": "\"UtPdadq\"",
    "password": "\"email1Password123\""
  },
  {
    "name": "Second",
    "second_name": "User",
    "age": "28",
    "email": "data2email@email.com",
    "user_id": "ehOFXzI",
    "password": "email2Password123"
  }
]
```

I'll give you the User class and the main function for more information

```
public class User {
    //user's variables
    String name;
    String second_name;
    String age;
    String email;
    String user_id; //automatically generated
    String password;


    //constructor without parameters
    public User(String nameUser, String second_name_user, String ageUser, String emailUser, String passwordUser) {}
    //coonstructor with parameters
    public User(String name, String second_name, String age, String email, String user_id, String password) {
        this.name = name;
        this.second_name = second_name;
        this.age = age;
        this.email = email;
        this.user_id = user_id;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public User() {

    }


    //Setters and getters
}
```

and the main

```
public static void signUp(String filename) {// add user
        System.out.println("Please, remember that you should restart this app when you are registered.");
        User new_user = new User();//new user's instance
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter data: ");
        System.out.println("==================");
        String id = generateUserId() ;
        System.out.println("Enter your email: ");
        String emailUser = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter your password: ");
        String passwordUser = ingressPassword();
        System.out.println("Enter your name: ");
        String nameUser = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter your second name: ");
        String second_name_User = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter your age: ");
        String ageUser = scanner.nextLine();

        new_user.setUser_id(id);
        new_user.setEmail(emailUser);
        new_user.setPassword(passwordUser);
        new_user.setName(nameUser);
        new_user.setSecond_name(second_name_User);
        new_user.setAge(ageUser);

        //Test
        //System.out.println(new_user.getClass());
        try
        {
            //new file instance at the path
            File file = new File(filename);
            //tries to create new file in the system
            boolean bool=file.createNewFile();
            Path path = Paths.get(filename);

            List< User > users = new ArrayList< >();


            if(bool){
                users.add(new_user);
                try (Writer writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
                    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();

                    JsonElement tree = gson.toJsonTree(users);
                    gson.toJson(tree, writer);
                }

                System.out.println("Users written to file");

            }else {
                try (Reader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(path,
                        StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
                    JsonObject car=null;
                    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
                    JsonElement tree = parser.parse(reader);

                    JsonArray array = tree.getAsJsonArray();

                    for (JsonElement element: array) {
                        if (element.isJsonObject()) {
                            car = element.getAsJsonObject();
                        }
                    }

                    String idPrev = car.get("user_id").toString();
                    String emailPrev = car.get("email").toString();
                    String passPrev = car.get("password").toString();
                    String namePrev = car.get("name").toString();
                    String snamePrev = car.get("second_name").toString();
                    String agePrev = car.get("age").toString();

                    //System.out.println(idPrev);
                    //add data to list
                    User userPrev = new User();

                    userPrev.setUser_id(idPrev);
                    System.out.println(userPrev.getUser_id());
                    userPrev.setEmail(emailPrev);
                    userPrev.setPassword(passPrev);
                    userPrev.setName(namePrev);
                    userPrev.setSecond_name(snamePrev);
                    userPrev.setAge(agePrev);

                    //two objects User: userPrev and new_user
                    System.out.println("*******************");
                    System.out.println(userPrev);
                    System.out.println("*******************");
                    System.out.println(new_user);
                    System.out.println("*******************");

                   //add User objects to the same List
                    users.add(userPrev);
                    users.add(new_user);

                    //json
                    try (Writer writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
                        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();

                        JsonElement tree2 = gson.toJsonTree(users);
                        gson.toJson(tree2, writer);//write
                    }

                    System.out.println("Users written to file");
                }
            }
        }catch (IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}
    }
```

Comment: `"\""` is for escaping of double quotes. Did you try to debug? What's the value of `idPrev ` at `String idPrev = car.get("user_id").toString();`? Does it have `"\""`?

Comment: If i made a print of String idPrev = car.get("user_id").toString(); i got "ehOFXzI" (id is random). Iknow that \" is for escaping double quotes  but the code saves them like i put in the question ( i don't know why)

Comment: Just a recommendation - you should always follow Java Naming Conventions, so field names should be in camel case (`user_id` => `userId`, `second_name` => `secondName`). It can save you much debug-time in future ;)

Comment: Hahaha... It's true. I'll do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 problems with your code.

1. You are reading just the previous object from file and overwriting the older objects. Which means the file will always have the last 2 objects and not older. (Unless this is what you intended.)
2. You are manually reading the json file and setting each attribute in `user` object. You should let Gson do this for you.

**So, delete following code**

```java
                    JsonObject car=null;
                    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
                    JsonElement tree = parser.parse(reader);

                    JsonArray array = tree.getAsJsonArray();

                    for (JsonElement element: array) {
                        if (element.isJsonObject()) {
                            car = element.getAsJsonObject();
                        }
                    }

                    String idPrev = car.get("user_id").toString();
                    String emailPrev = car.get("email").toString();
                    String passPrev = car.get("password").toString();
                    String namePrev = car.get("name").toString();
                    String snamePrev = car.get("second_name").toString();
                    String agePrev = car.get("age").toString();

                    //System.out.println(idPrev);
                    //add data to list
                    User userPrev = new User();

                    userPrev.setUser_id(idPrev);
                    System.out.println(userPrev.getUser_id());
                    userPrev.setEmail(emailPrev);
                    userPrev.setPassword(passPrev);
                    userPrev.setName(namePrev);
                    userPrev.setSecond_name(snamePrev);
                    userPrev.setAge(agePrev);

                    //two objects User: userPrev and new_user
                    System.out.println("*******************");
                    System.out.println(userPrev);
                    System.out.println("*******************");
                    System.out.println(new_user);
                    System.out.println("*******************");

                   //add User objects to the same List
                    users.add(userPrev);
```

**and replace with single line**

```java
users = new Gson().fromJson(reader, new TypeToken<List<User>>(){}.getType());
```

**Here is the complete code**

```java
public class GsonWriteToFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        signUp("gson-file.txt");
    }

    public static void signUp(String filename) {// add user
        System.out.println("Please, remember that you should restart this app when you are registered.");
        User new_user = new User();//new user's instance
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter data: ");
        System.out.println("==================");
        String id = "randomId";// Use generateUserId() ; here
        System.out.println("Enter your email: ");
        String emailUser = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter your password: ");
        String passwordUser = scanner.nextLine();// use ingressPassword(); here
        System.out.println("Enter your name: ");
        String nameUser = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter your second name: ");
        String second_name_User = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter your age: ");
        String ageUser = scanner.nextLine();

        new_user.setUser_id(id);
        new_user.setEmail(emailUser);
        new_user.setPassword(passwordUser);
        new_user.setName(nameUser);
        new_user.setSecond_name(second_name_User);
        new_user.setAge(ageUser);

        //Test
        //System.out.println(new_user.getClass());
        try {
            //new file instance at the path
            File file = new File(filename);
            //tries to create new file in the system
            boolean bool = file.createNewFile();
            Path path = Paths.get(filename);

            List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();


            if (bool) {
                users.add(new_user);
                try (Writer writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
                    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();

                    JsonElement tree = gson.toJsonTree(users);
                    gson.toJson(tree, writer);
                }

                System.out.println("Users written to file");

            } else {
                try (Reader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(path,
                        StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
                    // change starts
                    users = new Gson().fromJson(reader, new TypeToken<List<User>>(){}.getType());
                   // change ends
                    users.add(new_user);

                    //json
                    try (Writer writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
                        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();

                        JsonElement tree2 = gson.toJsonTree(users);
                        gson.toJson(tree2, writer);//write
                    }

                    System.out.println("Users written to file");
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your help. Really apreciated!! In second order, i was trying to "read" de previous object and overwrite my file with that and the new one. I thought it could be updated every time that an user was registered. I understand that your single Gson line extracts it in a arraylist, so i used it with my try and writer order to test it but i cannot add it to my json file.

Comment: I have updated my answer with complete code. Try it out, I have added code comments wherever I have made a change to your code.

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much! I was trying many days because i didn't work with Gson before. Thank you again!.