# How can I add data to a JSON on Java?

Tags: java, json

I was wondering already having an existing .json file how can I add more information to it without having to delete it and write it again. For now I have this code, but I cannot add new information to it.

```
public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        //First Employee
        JSONObject employeeDetails = new JSONObject();
        employeeDetails.put("firstName", "Lokesh");
        employeeDetails.put("lastName", "Gupta");
        employeeDetails.put("website", "howtodoinjava.com");

        JSONObject employeeObject = new JSONObject(); 
        employeeObject.put("employee", employeeDetails);

        //Second Employee
        JSONObject employeeDetails2 = new JSONObject();
        employeeDetails2.put("firstName", "Brian");
        employeeDetails2.put("lastName", "Schultz");
        employeeDetails2.put("website", "example.com");

        JSONObject employeeObject2 = new JSONObject(); 
        employeeObject2.put("employee", employeeDetails2);

        //Add employees to list
        JSONArray employeeList = new JSONArray();
        employeeList.add(employeeObject);
        employeeList.add(employeeObject2);

        //Write JSON file
        try (FileWriter file = new FileWriter("employees.json")) {

            file.write(employeeList.toJSONString());
            file.flush();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hello did you check this before: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36178762/13569412

Comment: You read the file content back in, using `JSONArray`, modify the data in memory, and write it back out.

Comment: You need to specify which JSON library you're using, if you want specific help.

Comment: Yes, I saw it, but I don't fully understand how to add information to an existing file. 
I'm using json-simple-1.1.1 library.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/61789289/1776132